# Flask, Display a picture outisde static folder

Tags: python, flask

I have a html page under **template\about\index.html**

Is it possible to display an image who is located in the same path -> **template\about\img.jpg** ??
I have try many ways but didn't manage to make it happen.

I want to avoid the use of the **static folder** in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[assume your application object is called app]

```
@app.route('/imgIFrame')

def imgIframe():
    with open('template/about/img.jpg') as fin:
        data = fin.read()
        ret = make_response(data, 200)
        ret.headers['Content-Type'] = 'img/jpeg'
        return ret
```

In your HTML you'll need an iframe populated by a call to that method and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a config.py file

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
APP_YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY= os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'template\about\')
```

and then you can import that path anywhere

```
from config import APP_YOUR_IMAGE
```